# Google OAuth 2.0 PHP API Authentication fails: "Use of undefined constant STDIN"

Tags: php, google-oauth, inputstream, stdin

I am trying to implement the `PlaylistItems: insert` [YouTube Data API sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert), and when I try to run it, I get the following:

**Notice**: Use of undefined constant STDIN - assumed 'STDIN' in **/example/path/to/script.php** on line **51**

The function containing this line does not make it clear where STDIN gets it's value:

```
function getClient() {
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName('API Samples');
  $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl');
  // Set to name/location of your client_secrets.json file.
  $client->setAuthConfig('client_secrets.json');
  $client->setAccessType('offline');

  // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
  $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
  } else {
    // Request authorization from the user.
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
    print 'Enter verification code: ';
    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN)); // <--- Appears to be the problem

    // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
    $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

    // Store the credentials to disk.
    if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
      mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
    printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
  }
  $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

  // Refresh the token if it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
  }
  return $client;
}
```

Please forgive my naiveté, but how is the script supposed to supply an auth code? Why is this step not performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, @sean-bright for pointing out the existing question. While it didn't not answer my question, it got me closer to the solution.

It turns out Google's sample is designed to be run from a CLI and my browser-based implementation was not providing a means of prompting the user for input that is called for by that `STDIN` line.

Since the auth code is provided as a parameter in the `$authUrl` variable that gets printed to the screen the first time the script is run, I was able to resolve my issue by replacing

`$authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));`

with:

`$authCode = $_GET['code'];`